# How to solve this error "Error using - Matrix dimensions must agree"

Tags: matlab

I will find mean of image by using `mean(template)` but it throws an error.
How can I solve this?

```
template = imread('template.bmp');

meanTemplate = mean(template);
sum1 = sum((template(1:66,1:32)-meanTemplate).^2);
```

Comment: Why do you load the first image if you don't use it at all?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: At least what are those sizes (i.e. values for `M`, `N`, `m`, `n`)?

Comment: I do template matching by using normalized cross-correlation and first image will using in next line code.

Comment: I will edit code and add values. thank you.

Comment: `mean(template)` will return a column vector. And I reckon you do want to subtract such column vector to every column in `template` (normalize with 0 mean). If that's the goal, I really suggest you to use `bsxfun()` (something like `newMatrix=bsxfun(@minus,template,mean(template))`. This will only work, however, if `mean(template)` returns a column vector with 66 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image `template` is a matrix such that `mean(template)` is a vector because the mean is computed along the first dimension. If you would like to compute the overall mean value of the image, you should first flatten the matrix into a vector, i.e. `meanTemplate = mean(template(:))`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do exactly,

but template(1:m,1:n) is of size n x m and meanTemplate of 1 x n. How is MATLAB supposed to calculate the difference? That does not make sense at all.

And btw...

```
template == template(1:m,1:n)
```